# Why is the achievements button's link border so large?

Tags: support, design, top-bar, achievements-dialog

When I click on the achievements button/menu I obviously get a dashed border around it, much as when you click on a link. I notice that this border is much wider than the achievements button.

[image]

Why is this? Is it possible for other things to be displayed there, subject to rep perhaps?

Comment: Sorry to all if this turns out to be the most fantastically tedious question, but I thought there might be secrets